# Thread issue in Xcode 9.0

Tags: swift, xcode, nsthread

I am getting some thread issues in xcode 9.0 (9A235), but if I run the same project on xcode 8.3 it works fine. To debug it further I tried putting

```
if !Thread.isMainThread {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Updating UI components here
    }
}
```

but still am getting the same issues.

This is the issue
[image]

What is this error and why it's coming when I am updating my UI components on Main thread. Is there a way by which I can come to know in which part of the code this is happening?

Please don't mark this question as a duplicate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Very likely you are still requesting something from the background...Are you requesting permission for showing notifications on background thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get rid of the issue by updating the Pod.

I just updated the FirebaseAnalytics to 4.0.3 which was 3.9.0 and all the thread related issues are gone.

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate Firebase for this; the offending queue name is FIRAnalyticsQueue. Seems that call might have something to do with it in your AppDelegate.